# Throwing an exception at the end of a method - bad practice?

Tags: exception, methods

I found this code on the internet, and rephrased it in pseudo to be more readable.

It just cannot get out of my head that there is something wrong with it regarding bad/good practice, common sense, etc. And I am not talking about too many returns and not about the fact that exception is thrown or not. It is about the way the method is structured around the flow.

It just looks weird if a method goes down the code and keeps breaking out in case of success or n/a and only if nothing made him return, it fails with exception at the end. Pretty similar/exact to

```java
switch { 
  case: validationNotNeeded;break;
  case: validationNotApplicable;break;
  case: validationSuccessful;break;
  default: throw new Exception()
}
```

Method (btw. the method could be also non-void one, then the return will be the some object or so):

```java
public void validateSomething(String param1, String param2)
throws ValidationException {

   if (param1 == null || param2 == null) {
       // no validation needed or cannot be performed
       return;
   }

   String someValue = someLogicToGetIt();
   if (someValue == null) {
       // no validation needed or cannot be done
       return;
   }

   if (someValue == "<expectedValue>") {
       // validation successful
       return;
   }

   // obviously validation did not succeed
   throw new ValidationException();
}
```

So, am I only having this feeling or there is some defined bad practice rule, referring exactly to this sort of methods, something like antipatern "switch-like fallthrough to default throwing exception" or is this just a combination of antipatterns "too many returns" and "exceptions for flow control"

Comment: You mean apart from using an exception to control flow?

Answer (score 1):

This really comes down to the intent of the original developer.

Maybe they have a requirement to crash when `someValue != "<expectedValue>"`

Maybe they have

```
try 
{
    validateSomething(param1, param2)
}
catch (ValidationException e)
{
     //do stuff here
}
```

Elsewhere in their code. While it might not be deemed best practice, they might have had a reason for it when initially implementing.

Comment: This does not change the situation at all. It is not about the fact that an exception is thrown on failed validation. It is about the way the method is structured. Actually this was mentioned in the question to prevent such answers :)

Comment: @radio assuming that `someLogicToGetIt();` uses param1 and param2 where would you throw the exception in the method? Are you proposing to move the exception elsewhere in the method or eliminate it altogether? I am not sure what you are asking exactly based on your comment.

Comment: @radio In the question, you also said it is not about the multiple returns ... so what *is* it about? To my latest knowledge, it is considered antipattern to use multiple returns and is considered antipattern to use exceptions for flow-control. So here we have the combination of two anti-patterns of which you say "it is not about them" - what else could it be about?

Comment: Hellyale, like @Fildor mentioned, the code is having two antipatterns: exceptions for flow control and too many returns. It is clear they are not fine. I am just wondering whether there is not a third antipattern like "switch-like fallthrough to default throwing exception" or something :) and if somebody knows about such a pattern I would like to know the name of it. If this code has only the previously mentioned antipatterns, then fine. When I think about it, looks like the "switch-like fallthrough to default throwing exception" is just a combination of both previously mentioned ones.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Yes, I guess that structure is inherent to the combination of the two. Yu nearly cannot combine the two without doing it like this.